# NullReferenceException until tile is spawned

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript, tiles

I have a tile and tile has enemies spawn positions, and spawner script in it. Everything works fine when tile is spawned, my ray hits the collider in tile and enemies get spawned, but my spawn script is in tile my ray script is in my player so im reaching from my PlayerMove script to spawner script, but until my tile is spawned i get this error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object because tile is not spawned yet after its spawned error stops, but after tile is deleted it starts again how can i get rid of this error.

PlayerScript

```
private Spawner spawner;
private RaycastHit hit;

private void Update()
{
  spawner = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Spawner").GetComponent<Spawner>();
  DrawRay();
}

private void DrawRay()
{

    Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0));

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit))
    {
        if(hit.collider.tag == "SpawnerCollider")
        {
            if(hit.distance < 5)
            {
                Destroy(hit.collider);
                spawner.Spawn();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SpawnerScript

```
public Transform[] spawnPos;
public GameObject fireBall;

public void Spawn()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < spawnPos.Length; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(fireBall, spawnPos[i].position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one of the most common types of errors in Unity, with multiple official docs and Q&A pages describing how to deal with it, so please do not neglect to search for existing information before asking a new question.

Comment: I know why im getting this error didn't you read what i wrote i said until my tile is spawned i get this error. I tried so much things to spawn enemies, but it worked properly with ray. I will try to explain more detailed, this is a 3D endless runner game, i have a tile spawner it spawns my tiles and delete them. One of my tile has my FireBall Spawner 12 empty gameobject for positions one gameobject for collider one gameobject for spawner script. When my player ray hits the collider Spawner script spawns 12 FireBall in different positions.

Comment: But im calling my spawn function from my player script to reah spawner script im using FindGameObjectWithTag, but when i call FindGameObjectWithTag in Update because it works with update it gives me error UNTIL my tile has spawned.

Comment: And the duplicate question linked above offers a solution to that problem: check for null before doing an operation that would trigger an exception. Try using the existing answer, and edit your question if you can't make it work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for help i tried checking null but it wasn't worked. i figured out that i don't need my spawner object i put my script to my bridge and then i checked null and it worked